# How to prove that $|Ax| \leq \|A\| |x|$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

In page 208 of Rudin's 'Principle of mathematical analysis' book it is written that

> For $A\in L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$ , define the norm $\|A\|$ of $A$  to be the sup of all numbers  $|Ax|$, where $x$ ranges over all vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ with $|x| \leq1.$

Next it is written that

> Observe that the inequality $$|Ax| \leq \|A\| |x|$$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb R^n.$

In the last part I am facing difficulties to understand.

Comment: It is almost certainly a duplicate Q but I haven't searched.

Comment: You should write $\|Ax\|,$  not $|Ax|,$ as $Ax\in \mathbb R^m$ and $m$ may be greater than $1.$

Comment: Another property of $\|A\|$ in the special case $m=1$: Let $d(x, A^{-1}\{0\})=\inf \{\|x-y\|: Ay=0\}.$ Then $|Ax|=\|A\|d(x,A^{-1}\{0\}).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet How can we sure that $\mathbf A^{-1}$ exists ?

Comment: The notation $A^{-1}S,$ when $A$ is a function, means $\{y: A(y)\in S\}.$  It does not mean that  $A^{-1}$ is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=0$ it's obvious. If $x\ne0$, then $\bigl\|\|x\|^{-1}x\bigr\|=1$, so
$$
\bigl\|A(\|x\|^{-1}x)\bigr\|\le \|A\|
$$
by definition.

Note that this shows you could just define
$$
\|A\|=\sup\{\|Ax\|:\|x\|=1\}
$$
Since $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x\|=1\}$ is closed and bounded, this is actually a maximum, so there exists $x_0$ with $\|x_0\|=1$ and $\|Ax_0\|=\|A\|$.

Answer (score 2):

When $x=0$, it is trivial. That inequality holds for $|x|>0$ by definition:
$$
\|A\|=\sup\{|Ax|:|x|\leq 1\}
$$
implies that 
$$
\|A\|\geq |A(\frac{x}{|x|})|.
$$

Comment: For $|x| \leq 1$ ,  $|Ax| \leq ||A||$ ( that is we know from definition) but how $|Ax| \leq ||A|| |x|$ for $|x| \leq 1$  holds.  May be it's so easy but I'm finding it not so..